# Windows Store App GestureSettings

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have difficulties with implementing `Holding` event on `Image` in a Metro app.

```
<Image Name="imgArrowUp" Source="Images/controls/arrow_up.png" Tapped="imgArrowUp_Tapped" Holding="imgArrowUp_Holding" />
```

`Tapped` event works just fine. But I can't manage to raise `Holding` event using mouse. I searched through internet and I found some information about `GestureSettings.HoldWithMouse`, but I don't get how to use it. I thought it is a XAML argument, but unfortunately it is not.

How can I raise `Holding` event on the image using left mouse button?

Comment: Clicking on the item and keeping pressed and not moving the mouse for a few seconds does not raise that event? Than probably, it's impossible thanks to yet-another-bright-idea at microsoft.. you see, Tap/Hold/etc events are for touchscreens, and I've heard quite a couple of times that this-or-that is not working because the MS "discourages" mixing and emulating touch/mouse with each other.. That is, you should use Mouse events for mouse, and touch events for touch, and implement similar behaviour twice..

Comment: I don't actually want support mouse holding. I need Holding for touch screen but I don't have any. I just want try if it works before Microsoft certification event.

Comment: You can use the simulator to simulate touch.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the simulator. Nevertheless, it doesn't solve my problem with Holding using mouse. I can't still manage to raise the event. Although it works with touch on the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159855/metro-app-holding-event-in-games) is an answer. Only problem was badly chosen event.

Although `Holding` event eventually worked well using tablet, it doesn't provide solution I was trying to find. Using `PointerPressed` and `PointerReleased` events solve the problem.